# When does a file actually get written to the disk?

Tags: c, architecture, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi, writing files to a micro SD card (Class 10) for data logging purposes. If the Pi experiences a loss of power I have noticed that the last several files are not written. Each file is about 3 KB in size. I know this because I have the Pi printing to the screen which file number it is on, and when I reboot it is several numbers back.

I have tried increasing the frequency that I create new files, and I lose the same amount of data time-wise (I lose more file numbers).

My question really is what is the low level process that writes the files to the physical SD Card? Once they are physically on the card, they should not be affected by the power down. My code is structured as follows:

- fopen new file
- fwrite contents of file
- fflush to flush the buffer to the file
- fclose to close the file pointer
- repeat with new file

My only theory is that once the Pi closes the file, it is up to the MMU to asynchronously write to the SD Card, and the files left in the "MMU queue" are lost on power down. Otherwise if fflush and fclose don't actually write to the disk then I'm not sure how any computer doesn't experience this loss every time it shuts down.

Comment: I should clarify that the SD card isn't used as an external memory device, it is the disk that the OS is installed on.

Comment: Well, given that writing flash is extremely slow, and very power-intensive compared with reading, I'm not surprised that the various cacheing mechanisms in the driver and SD-card internal controller, are um..  'more write-optimized than secure' :(  What file system do you use?

Comment: `fflush` just flushes the buffer of your standard library, so the data is completely passed to the OS. With standard C, there's no way to control what the OS does. But you could use POSIX `open()` with `O_SYNC` maybe...

Comment: It depends on factors outside the program's control via standard C.  The actual write time may be sub-millisecond to seconds delayed, in _general_, even _after_ the program closes. IDK about raspberry-pi

Comment: Okay, I will try @FeloxPalmen 's idea of using the POSIX functions, as for martin's question I believe its FAT32? None of these answers give me the warm fuzzy that I'll be able to reduce this :/

Answer (score 0):

IMO the file get buffered in block device, so try to mount your file system with 'sync' option or use sync() to force changed blocks to disk.